# Yii setFlash with Logout

Tags: php, yii

Im tying to use the command sequence:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Successful!");
Yii::app()->user->logout();
$this->redirect(array('user/login'));
```

The user got logged out and redirected, but the Setflash does not work.
I also tried to change the order of 2 frist commands, but got the same problem.
If I do not logout the user, the Setflash works fine.

How can I make both commands work?

Comment: You try with the inverse: Yii::app()->user->logout(); Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Successful!"); ?

Comment: I tried, but do do not worked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash messages are stored in the session. Logging the user our destroys the user's current session. Once session_destroy() is called, you must call session_start() again in order to generate a new session ID and have this work. Yii most likely does not do that.

If it's that important that you have a "Successful" message indicating that the logout worked - then redirect the user to a "logout successful" page. Alternatively, you can look into overriding the way Yii performs a logout - although I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 6):

this should work

```
Yii::app()->user->logout();
Yii::app()->session->open();
Yii::app()->user->setFlash(...);
```

If you need to destroy a whole session but you want to set a flash afterwards, you may extends CWebUser this way:

```
<?php

class BaseWebUser extends CWebUser
{

        public function logout($destroySession = true)
        {
                parent::logout($destroySession);
                Yii::app()->session->open();
        }

}

?>
```

have a closer look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7077-setflashgetflash-problem/page__view__findpost__p__37096)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this :

```
public function afterLogout() {
    // Create new session
    $session=new CHttpSession;
    $session->open();

    // Set flash message
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'You are logged out successfully.');

    // Prepare target URL after logout
    $continue_url = Yii::app()->request->hostInfo . Yii::app()->createUrl('');

    // Redirect
    CController::redirect($continue_url);
}
```

Put it inside your WebUser components.